# jQuery - Count list children not containing div with class

Tags: jquery, html-lists, jquery-traversing

I have a simple js script that counts the number of children an unordered list has.  I'm trying to change the script so it doesn't count any children (li) which contain a div with the class 'hiddenItem'.  Here's the list and the js.

```
    <ul id="dlist" class="sortable">
        <li id="listItem_000002">
            <div>
                <div><a class="itemCollapse"></a>
                </div>Item 2</div>
        </li>
        <li id="listItem_000003">
            <div>
                <div><a class="itemCollapse"></a>
                </div>Item 3</div>
        </li>
        <li id="listItem_000009">
            <div>
                <div><a class="itemCollapse"></a>
                </div>Item 9</div>
        </li>
        <li id="listItem_000012">
            <div class="hiddenItem">
                <div><a class="itemCollapse"></a>
                </div>Item 12 (Hidden)</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <br>

    <a class="count">Count</a>
```

.

```
    $(".count").click(function () {
        var tcount = $("#dlist").children("li").length;
        alert(tcount);
    });
```

In this example the js  alerts that there are 4 items. But, I'm trying to change the code so it alerts 3 items, due to the last list item containing the div with the class 'hiddenItem.'  I've tried to use .filter() as well as a few other transverseing methods with no luck. Anyone have a better idea?

Here's  a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YeDdq/1/

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `not` method.

```
var tcount = $("#dlist > li").not(':has(div.hiddenItem)').length;
```

Or `filter` method:

```
var tcount = $("#dlist > li").filter(function(){
                 return $('div.hiddenItem', this).length === 0;
             }).length;
```

Comment: Ah, brilliant suggestion. I completely forgot about the not method and it makes plenty sense. Thanks! Cheers!

Comment: Answer accepted  and here's an updated fiddle for those who come along later.. http://jsfiddle.net/YeDdq/10/

Thanks undefined!

Answer (score 5):

[.not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) works, and it's more readable:

```
$('#dlist > li').not('.hiddenItem').length;
```

Edit: just realized the first answer also has .not listed, but I'm not sure why they made it so complicated with the `has` pseudo-class.

Answer (score 1):

Filter should definitely do want you want in this instance.  From your fiddle:

```
$(".count").click(function () {
    var tcount = $("#dlist").children("li")
    .filter(function() { return !($(this).children().is('.hiddenItem')); })
    .length;
    alert(tcount);
});
```

I've updated your fiddle to reflect this:
http://jsfiddle.net/YeDdq/8/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the :not and :has selectors

```
$(function() {
    var tcount = $("#dlist li:not(:has(.hiddenItem))").length;
    alert(tcount);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var tcount = $("#dlist > li").filter(function(){
                                         return $(this).find(".hiddenItem")
                                                       .length==0;
                                     }).length
```